# gujarati fonts not display properly from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, fonts

we are using this code but Gujarati fonts not display properly on browser ...
my sq l about field have this text "ફૂટપાથ વગરના રોડ ઉપર રાહદારીએ શું કરવું?"

```
<?


        $query = MySQL_query($con,"SELECT * FROM guj1") or die(mysqli_error());
        if(MySQL_nun_rows($query)){
            while($row=MySQL_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo utf8_decode($row['about']);    
            }
        }
        MySQL_close($con); 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on top of your PHP code !

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

### In your code like..

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8'); //<=---- Add here


        $query = MySQL_query($con,"SELECT * FROM guj1") or die(mysqli_error());
        if(MySQL_nun_rows($query)){
            while($row=MySQL_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo utf8_decode($row['about']);    
            }
        }
        MySQL_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: hi shankar damodaran i am use mysql field utf8_general_ci but it's show "?????? ????? ??? ??? ???????? ??? ?????? " now

Comment: @user3265795, Did you add the line above as shown ?

Comment: yes thanks bro.. its working fine now

Answer (score 2):

Probably not setting the Connection Character Sets and Collations correctly which can be done with the following

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Include `utf-8` header at start of your file

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```